# Error code: 2013: Lost connection to Mysql server during the query.. How can improve this query

Tags: mysql

I am getting the error stated in my post title. I have two tables. The first one, large is over than 4000,000 records and the second, small one is arounf 7000 records. I want to search for the value in the samll table and if found, I want to extract the whole record from the large table. The command never executed and always lose the connection with the database. I tried to limit the out put to 50 records only, the same thing happens. Please help me. If I need something like indexing (I read this might solve such performance problems, please clarify to me how. I'm not a DBA).

```
select * from db.large, db.small 
where large.value=small.value;
```

**EDIT: ** I use MySQL workbench 5.2.41 CE.

Comment: Please post the tables' structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLE` output).

Answer (score 0):

At one point on a previous project, I could actually crash the MySQL server reproducibly with a pretty simple query. In the code that called the database, I saw the same error message. Can you verify that the MySQL server's process ID is the same before and after the query? Chances are that your OS restarts the MySQL server immediately after the crash, and the MySQL command line client automatically reconnects (though it emits a notice when it does).